# Identifying an 11 digit timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp

I've been working with a dataset from a client that contains 11 digits as a timestamp. Here are some examples:
[image]

The only clues I have are that the dates are supposed to be for the year 2013, and that days_spent is the difference between date_admitted and date_discharged in number of days.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that these are tenths of a second.  So, divide by ten and add this as a number of seconds to 1970-01-01.

In standard SQL, you could convert them as:

```
select date '1970-01-01' + (date_admitted / 10) * interval '1 second'
```

This is possible in any database, but the syntax varies.

Comment: Yep, looks like time from 1970 in 0.1 seconds steps. @Kai You'll need to try the formula above and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to help me out! Assuming these are a tenths of a second does lead to the year being 2013, but unfortunately it didn't quite match the days_spent column... if you have any other ideas that would be great! Been wrestling with this for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a similar dataset with 11-digits timestamps and spent hours trying to figure out what they represented... After a lot of trials I was able to find the answer, that I share here for everyone that will experience the same situation.

These timestamps represent the number of seconds since the 4th of October, 1582, which happens to be the date in which the Gregorian Calendar was introduced.

In my case, the test that I did in SQL to understand this consisted of subtracting from one of the dates that I had in the dataset the corresponding number of seconds in the timestamp:

```
select TO_DATE('01/12/2021 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') - numToDSInterval((13857696000/60), 'minute') from dual;
```

And this returned 04-OTT-1582 00:00:00.

I did a few tests with your data too and I think this is the case also for your dataset.